# Dropdown CSS Menu Breaking

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, z-index

I have a CSS menu with a dropdown using pseudo :hover tags, but for some reason it keeps breaking (acting as if it's out of the ul) whenever I move the mouse over the wrapper/body. I tried using  z-index, but that didn't fix it either. Help!

Mouse over "Menu" button.

[live.bluefantail.com/demo.php](http://live.bluefantail.com/demo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `z-index` to `#content`:

```
#content {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Shoot. I had that but I accidentally didn't comment out something properly in the CSS and it wasn't taking affect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i didnt understand your problem but their is one more issue with your site.
Your footer moves over the content when resizing the browser.